# Invalid common user or role name

Tags: oracle

why is this showing error..

```
SQL> create user nisar identified by kk ;
create user nisar identified by kk
            *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to create a common user, not a container user, with an invalid name:

> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
>   Cause: An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name that wass not valid for common users or roles. In addition to the usual rules for user and role names, common user and role names must start with C## or c## and consist only of ASCII characters.
>   Action: Specify a valid common user or role name.

If you want to create a user in a particular container then you can use the `alter session set container` first, so your `create` is applied within that container. If you really do want a common user, follow the naming rules above.

[Read more in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#CNCPT89257).

Answer (score 64):

I had used below command. It's very useful. So, I would like to recommend to you.

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

For more information, see:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_65096_create_user_12c_without_c_prefix.htm

Comment: I also used above and it worked for me and since I dont use CDB/PDB currently, I dont care much if I created it for container db or pluggable db. So what I wanted to know why this has been voted down? If there is any -ve impact of it, I'd avoid it. Thanks

Comment: I've got the issue during Data Miner installation. This query doesn't work for me :/