# How can I install the sample schemas?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm learning Oracle 12c using the book [Oracle Database 12c Install, Configure & Maintain Like a Pro](http://www.ebooks.com/1122783/oracle-database-12c-install-configure-amp-maintain-like-a-professional/abramson-ian-abbey-michael-malcher-michelle/). I installed the database, but I didn't find the sample schemas (tables like Customers, Sales, products ...). So I download [Oracle Database 12c Release 1 Examples (12.1.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-1968077.html) and installed it; but I still don't know how to get the sample tables.

From SQL Developer I ran `mksample.sql` to install all the sample schemas but I got:

```
Error starting at line 119 in command:
DROP USER hr CASCADE
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.

Error starting at line 120 in command:
DROP USER oe CASCADE
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'OE' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.

Error starting at line 121 in command:
DROP USER pm CASCADE
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'PM' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.
....
```

How can I fix this?

**update**: when i run hr_main.sql I get this after I enter 5 times a password:

```
specify password for HR as parameter 1:
specify default tablespeace for HR as parameter 2:
specify temporary tablespace for HR as parameter 3:
specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
specify log path as parameter 5:

Error starting at line 63 in command:
DROP USER hr CASCADE
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.

Error starting at line 72 in command:
CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED BY oracle12c
Error at Command Line:72 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name


Error starting at line 74 in command:
ALTER USER hr DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs
              QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.

Error starting at line 77 in command:
ALTER USER hr TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.

Error starting at line 79 in command:
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE VIEW, ALTER SESSION, CREATE SEQUENCE TO hr
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.

Error starting at line 80 in command:
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE DATABASE LINK, RESOURCE , UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO hr
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
Connected

Error starting at line 87 in command:
GRANT execute ON sys.dbms_stats TO hr
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
Error starting at line 93 in command:
CONNECT hr/&pass
Error report:
Connection Failed
Commit
```

Comment: [`mksample.sql` drops the users before (re-)creating them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15979/scripts.htm#COMSC004). It's a kind of protective delete. The errors on `drop` don't matter. Are the users then created successfully? Do they appear in `ALL_USERS`?

Comment: in sql developer, when i expand other users, No I do not find them.

Comment: OK, assuming you've refreshed that view, what errors do you get when it creates the users; when it runs the `hr_main.sql` script? If there are any, they will be more informative than the `drop` errors, which are expected at this point.

Comment: @AlexPoole, if you give me the SQL files that create all the tables I think that will solve it because I think somthing is wrong with the ones tha i have!!!!!!

Comment: I don't have 12c so can't check if the scripts are right; its feasible they haven't been updated yet I suppose. But [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22886961/266304). You need to run this in a container DB - but not sure if you'd need to `alter session` after each `connect`. Are you sure the schemas don't already exist in a container?

Comment: I don't know what it is a container DB, i'm a beginner, but when i create the database i make a plugable db linked to a container. is there any forum for 12c, so I can search help there. Thanks man for your interset.

Comment: You might want to start with [the concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234). My understanding is you need to connect to the container, but you're currently connected to the root. But I haven't played with this yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26592098/733092 helped me with this.