# Oracle Database12c ORA 01918 and connection error

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have installed the Oracle 12c and I have  problems creating my first database and using it.
I run SQL Developer and use "hr" user but it keeps telling me that the account is locked. I searched into stackoverflow answers and official doc and tried to unlock it with:

```
ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

but with no success. I got error ORA01918, meaning that user does not exist.

I tried then to use the user created at the installation (SYS as SYSDBA)but then it says that the user/password is incorrect. I am pretty sure that I have installed Oracle 12c correctly on my system, which is Windows 8.1 x64.

What should I do? Please help me.

Other thing I do not understand is wether or not the term "database" is equivalent to MySQL's "Schema"? The "connection" is to connect to a specific database, yes?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you running this in the container database or in a pluggable database? Exactly how are you connecting as HR and to try to unlock that account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you configure your database? Did you check the option for `Pluggable database`? If yes,  please make sure you login to `PDB` and not `CDB`.

Please read [**Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/).

By default, `pre-installed` users like `SCOTT`, `HR` etc. resides in `container database` and not in `pluggable database`.

**tnsnames.ora**

Edit your tnsnames.ora file to add the PDB details. For example,

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

**Open all PDBs**

To open all/specific PDBs immediately after logon, create a **AFTER STARTUP** system level trigger in CDB.

Since, the PDBs are not open through a CDB start. Let’s see :

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;

SQL> SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs;

NAME                           OPEN_MODE
------------------------------ ----------
PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY
PDBP6                          MOUNTED
```

So, in order to have all the PDBs automatically open, do this :

Do, “**`SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA`**”, and then execute :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER open_pdbs 
  AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE 
BEGIN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN'; 
END open_pdbs;
/
```

It creates a after startup system level trigger in CDB.

**SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA**

The most common misunderstanding is about “SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA” usage.

Since we have checked the option to create a single **CDB**, the “SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA” command will always log into CDB. Usually developers used to unlock the “SCOTT” account directly after logging as SYSDBA. But here is the trick :

**“SCOTT” and other sample schemas are in the PDB and not in the CDB**. So, you need to login as sysdba into PDB.

```
sqlplus SYS/password@PDBORCL AS SYSDBA

SQL> ALTER USER scott ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY tiger;

sqlplus scott/tiger@pdborcl

SQL> show user;
USER is "SCOTT"
```

Comment: I think I'm running pluggable database. I'm not sure how to verify this. I will read your tutorial. I hope in 1 day or two to come back with an answer. Thank you all for feedback

Comment: Sure, follow the steps as I mentioned in my article. Let me know if you have any problems :-)

Comment: I followed the steps from your article and it, finally, works! Thank you. I also have a question (sorry for off topic): although not enabled at startup, the Oracle services are consuming a lot of memory(my computer stays at about 2GB RAM ). Is there a posibility to start them only on demand?

Comment: Depends on the operating system. For example, if it is Windows, you can disbale the Oracle services from services.msc. By the way, if you think your topic has been answered, please mark it answered.

Comment: This worked! After twenty other tabs' worth of directions failed. Thank you so much.