# How to set the TWO_TASK Variable for installing Oracle 12c Sample Schemas?

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

I'm new at stack overflow and I have a problem with the Oracle 12C Enterprise Edition sample schemas. I've been searching and trying since days now and I'm really getting mad with this thing. I never used Oracle Databases before, so my knowledge about it is pretty small ;). I really hope that someone here can help me to find a solution :).

Some more information about my system: I am using the Release 12.1.0.1.0 of the Oracle 12c DB Enterprise Edition. The database is running on Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit.

My goal is, to install all the sample schemas (HR, OE, PM, IX, SH). During the installation of the Oracle Database, the sample schemas can be installed automatically, which didn't work for me (no Tables were created). So I decided to create the sample schemas using the demo scripts (https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas).

When i try to start the hr_main.sql using SQL Plus, the first Error I get is: 'ORA-65096: Invalid common user or role name.' My problem is actually the same as described in the Oracle Community: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2592334?start=0&tstart=0

I found out, that it's not possible to create HR as common user. So I decided to change all statements regarding user 'hr' in the hr-scripts (hr_main.sql, etc.) to 'C##hr'. That actually worked and it was my first achievement after trying to get it working for days. Great thing, I thought, but now I want to install the other sample schemas, too. And the same practice like I did with the hr user isn't really useful to create the others (oe, pm, ...). I tried, but it took a long time and I finally had to give up.

Now, I tried several times to follow the instructions given by the community users of oracle (link above) and tried to set the TWO_TASK variable. 
What I tried is:

1. in ...product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora my PDB is:

   ORCL2 =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pstestcons.corproot.net)(PORT = 1522))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = orcl2.corproot.net)
   )
   )
2. setting the TWO_TASK variable (I also tried set TWO_TASK=orcl2, don't know which one is correct) to the PDB on windows command line:

   > > set LOCAL=orcl2
3. when I connect to sqlplus using sys/password as sysdba and enter

   > > 'SQL> show con_name'

the result is

> > 'CON_NAME--------------------- CDB$ROOT'

and not my PDB as described in the answers of the oracle community. I don't know why, as i said, I'm not an expert with these Oracle things :P. I think this is not correct.

4. run the script hr_main.sql (SQL>@C:...\hr_main.sql)

*Then I get Errors over Errors, starting with Ora-65096 (Invalid Username). 
Has anyone an idea what to do? I'm happy with every advice!*

Comment: Why are you creating the HR user (as C##HR) in the CDB instead of your PDB?

Comment: By running the hr_main.sql script, it creates the user per default in the CDB... I don't know how to create it in PDB, in a way that I don't have to modifiy all sample scripts...

Comment: I haven't looked at the scripts in detail, but maybe you just need to [set the container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22886961/266304) to the PDB instead of the default root? Also check the schemas don't already exist there, if you asked for them to be created - you may have been looking in the root container for those instead too.